# PHP variable not displaying on page

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

I am trying to display a variable from php i get from a mySQLi Server. However, it only displays an empty String as 'name' variable.

My code is:

```
$GLOBALS[name] = "";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("<br>Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    $out = "Error when connecting to the database.";
} else {
    echo "<br>Connected successfully";
    $sql = "SELECT name, pwd FROM server1.us WHERE UPPER(eml) = UPPER('$email')";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $pwdHash = "";

    if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
        $out = "Your email is not registered yet.";
    }
    else {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $pwdHash = $row['pwd'];
        }
    }

    if (password_verify($pwd, $pwdHash) == false) {
        $out = "Your passwords do not match!";
    }
    else if($email == '') {
        $out = "You have to input an email.";
    }       
    else if($pwd == '') {
        $out = "You have to input a password.";
    }
    else {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $name = $row['name'];
    }
}
$conn->close();
```

My code to display the value:

```
<?php
        if($out == null) {
            echo "<h3>Thank you for logging in, $name!</h3>";
            echo "<p>You will be redirected...</p>";
        } else {
            echo "<h3>Oops! Apparently something went wrong...</h3>";
            echo "<p>$out</p>";
            echo "<p>You can try again <a data-toggle='modal' data-target='#loginModal'>here</a> .</p>";
        }
?>
```

When executed, no error is given, but the output is

> Thank you for logging in, ''!
>     You will be redirected...

My table in the database has following columns:

```
id
name
eml
pwd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `$result->fetch_assoc()` twice (first when you want to check the password, then later when you want to get the name). You shouldn't do that. Just call it once, not in a loop:

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$pwdHash = "";

if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
    $out = "Your email is not registered yet.";
}
else {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $pwdHash = $row['pwd'];
}

// [...]

$name = $row['name'];
```

Also, from your first line `$GLOBALS[name] = "";`, I'm assuming this code is executed in a function, and you want the `$name` variable to be global, and thus be accessible in your view later.

If that is what you want, you should use the `global` keyword:

```
global $name;
$name = $row['name'];
```

Of note: the way you inject user-provided data `$email` into your SQL query is very dangerous. Read some about SQL injection.

Comment: Using global throws an Internal Server Error. Also, you're missing a semicolon on

$row= $result->fetch_assoc();

if I'm not mistaken.